# apex email to case image not showing in Description field(RichText)

Tags: apex, files, apex-email-service, email2case, singleemailmessage

I have the following code to create Email-to-Case using Apex. The issue I am having is when an image is sent in the email body I am getting a broken image. can someone point me what is the mistake with this code or how I can show the image in the Description field(Rich TextArea).

```
global class EmailtoCaseCL implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email,Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){  
        
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
        List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();
        List<ContentVersion> lstCV = new List<ContentVersion>();
        List<ContentDocumentLink> lstCDL = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        
        try {
            
            if(email.binaryAttachments <> null)
            {
                for(Integer msgct =0;msgct<email.binaryAttachments.size();msgct++){
                    if(String.valueof(email.binaryAttachments[msgct]).length() <> 0 && email.binaryAttachments[msgct] <> null){
                        Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment binAttach = email.binaryAttachments[msgct];
                        ContentVersion singleFile = new ContentVersion();
                        singleFile.Title = binAttach.fileName;
                        singleFile.VersionData = binAttach.body;
                        singleFile.PathOnClient = '/' + binAttach.fileName ;
                        lstCV.add(singleFile);   
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(lstCV.size() >0)
                insert lstCV;
            
            //New SR creation process
            Case newEmailSR = new Case();
            newEmailSR.Status = 'Open';
            newEmailSR.Origin = 'Email'   ;                                                      
            newEmailSR.Subject =  email.subject;
            newEmailSR.Description = email.plainTextBody; 
            newEmailSR.Description__c = email.htmlBody;
            newEmailSR.OwnerId = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name = 'Email' AND Type = 'queue' LIMIT 1].Id;
            lstCase.add( newEmailSR);  
            if(lstCase.size() > 0)
            {
                insert lstCase;
            }            
                        
            //Email message insert code
            List<EmailMessage> newEmail = new List<EmailMessage>();
            EmailMessage newSREmail = new EmailMessage();
            newSREmail.FromAddress = email.fromAddress;
            newSREmail.FromName = email.fromName;
            newSREmail.BccIds = null;
            newSREmail.Subject =  email.subject;
            newSREmail.TextBody = email.plainTextBody;
            newSREmail.HtmlBody = email.htmlBody;
            newSREmail.RelatedToId  = lstCase[0].Id;
            newSREmail.ParentId = lstCase[0].Id;                                        
            newEmail.add( newSREmail);     
            
            if(newEmail.size() >0)
                insert newEmail;   
            
            lstCV = [select id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion WHERE Id in :lstCV];
            for (ContentVersion cv : lstCV) {
                ContentDocumentLink cl = new ContentDocumentLink();
                cl.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
                cl.LinkedEntityId = lstCase[0].Id;
                cl.ShareType = 'V';
                cl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                lstCDL.add(cl);
            }
            if(lstCDL.size() >0)
                insert lstCDL;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('**** Exception : ' + e);
        }
        
        result.success = true;    
        return result;
    }     
}
```

[image]

The HTML Code:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ligatures:standardcontextual;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72" style="word-wrap:break-word">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">Test email <o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="mso-ligatures:none"><img width="645" height="377" style="width:6.7222in;height:3.9236in" id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01D935C5.92AA8B20"></span><o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Broken image where? in the case description?

Comment: @Damecek Yes in Case Object --> Description field. The description field is Rich Text.

Comment: what's the url of the broken image?

Comment: Hi @NickCook it's not giving any URL just I see a broken image in the description field which is of type RickText. I have added the image screenshot with my question.

Comment: @Tamil There has to be a URL for it to be an image.  What's the actual html for the broken image?

Comment: Hi @NickCook I have updated the HTML code in my question. The image is coming as "cid:image001.png@01D935C5.92AA8B20". I am able to see the image in Files Tab.